# Where can I call my function so I can test it?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm currently working on this code and I know I have to call the function to test it but I am unsure which line I call the function on. I want to call sim_yahtzee(1,5) for my first test, how do I know where to call this in all these lines of code? Thanks

```
def sim_yahtzee(nrolls,n,sides=6):
    first_roll = []
    for i in range (n):
        rn = random.randint(1,6)
        first_roll.append(rn)
    number_one = first_roll.count(1)
    number_two = first_roll.count(2)
    number_three = first_roll.count(3)
    number_four = first_roll.count(4)
    number_five = first_roll.count(5)
    number_six = first_roll.count(6)
    for i in range (nrolls):
        if number_one > number_two and number_three and number_four and number_five and number_six:
            keep = [1] * number_one
        elif number_two > number_one and number_three and number_four and number_five and number_six:
            keep = [2] * number_two
        elif number_three > number_one and number_two and number_four and number_five and number_six:
            keep = [3] * number_three
        elif number_four > number_one and number_two and number_three and number_five and number_six:
            keep = [4] * number_four
        elif number_five > number_one and number_two and number_three and number_four and number_six:
            keep = [5] * number_five
        elif number_six >= number_one and number_two and number_three and number_four and number_five:
            keep = [6] * number_six
        elif number_five == number_four or number_three or number_two or number_one:
            keep = [5] * number_five
        elif number_four == number_three or number_two or number_one:
            keep = [4] * number_four
        elif number_three == number_two or number_one:
            keep = [3] * number_three
        elif number_two == number_one:
            keep = [2] * number_two
        reroll = []
        for i in range (len(first_roll)-len(keep)):
            rn = random.randint(1,6)
            reroll.append(rn)
        first_roll = (keep + reroll)
print (first_roll)
```

Comment: This code sample has more issues than just where to call a function (indentation, `if x > y and z`, etc.). You might want to look into some tutorials and examples.

Comment: i'm confused about what you're asking.  you probably don't want to call it from within itself, right?  also, yeah, `if a == b or c` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: I know I use a lot of if statements but sadly its one of the only things I understand in my python class. They do do what I want them to do but thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you always need to call a function after you define it in a python script. In you example, you could call it with

```
def sim_yahtzee(nrolls,n,sides=6):
    first_roll = []
    for i in range (n):
        rn = random.randint(1,6)
        first_roll.append(rn)
        number_one = first_roll.count(1)
        number_two = first_roll.count(2)
        number_three = first_roll.count(3)
        number_four = first_roll.count(4)
        number_five = first_roll.count(5)
        number_six = first_roll.count(6)
        for i in range (nrolls):
            if number_one > number_two and number_three and number_four and number_five and number_six:
                keep = [1] * number_one
            elif number_two > number_one and number_three and number_four and number_five and number_six:
                keep = [2] * number_two
            elif number_three > number_one and number_two and number_four and number_five and number_six:
                keep = [3] * number_three
            elif number_four > number_one and number_two and number_three and number_five and number_six:
                keep = [4] * number_four
            elif number_five > number_one and number_two and number_three and number_four and number_six:
                keep = [5] * number_five
            elif number_six >= number_one and number_two and number_three and number_four and number_five:
                keep = [6] * number_six
            elif number_five == number_four or number_three or number_two or number_one:
                keep = [5] * number_five
            elif number_four == number_three or number_two or number_one:
                keep = [4] * number_four
            elif number_three == number_two or number_one:
                keep = [3] * number_three
            elif number_two == number_one:
                keep = [2] * number_two
            reroll = []
            for i in range (len(first_roll)-len(keep)):
                rn = random.randint(1,6)
                reroll.append(rn)
            first_roll = (keep + reroll)
    print (first_roll)

sim_yahtzee(1,5)
```

Also, I've changed the indent, I assumed the loop should be inside the function. The indentation level replaces end statements in python.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "for" loops are properly indented!

You can call the function anywhere after defining it by typing the function's name with its args as its own line. In order to receive output from a function, you will need to use the "return" statement to return a variable, as any variables you initialize within a function will vanish after the function completes.

Consider putting:

```
return first_roll
```

as the last line of your function, and calling the function with

```
print(sim_yahtzee(6,6,sides=6))
```

one the first unindented line outside of the function. This will print the returned variable, first_roll.